# Can you claim a Double Sacrifice Bonus?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Two very closely related questions:

If a card has two different "Sacrifice this creature for X" abilities on it, does sacrificing it give both benefits?

Likewise, if a card requires a creature to be sacrificed, but that creature has a "Sacrifice this creature for X" ability, do you get the sacrifice benefit when you sacrifice it for the other requirement?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No to both - each ability has an individual cost, which you'll need to fulfill before it is put on the stack.

Anytime you see `Sacrifice [X]: Do [Y]`, that is expressing a cost that must be paid in order to activate the ability.  A single paid cost may not activate multiple abilities; see the following (from the comp. rules):

> **117.10.** Each payment of a cost applies to only one spell, ability, or effect. For example, a player can't sacrifice just one creature to activate the activated abilities of two permanents that each require sacrificing a creature as a cost. Also, the resolution of a spell or ability doesn't pay another spell or ability's cost, even if part of its effect is doing the same thing the other cost asks for.

Comment: To offer a slightly different way to think about it: an ability that says "Sacrifice [X]: Do [Y]" does **not** mean that "[Y]" automatically happens whenever you sacrifice [X]. And in general, it's _not_ the case that the effect of an ability occurs whenever you happen to take the action specified in the cost. You have to specifically choose to use a particular ability in order to get its effect, as Ian said.

Comment: And to make it really intuitively obvious: when you pay mana as a cost, you don't get to reuse it either.

Comment: @Jefromi When Ian pointed out it was a cost then I immediately thought of not being able to reuse mana.

Answer (score 2):

No, for the reasons given by Ian, however, if the card had read "Whenever a creature is sacrificed do X.  Sacrifice a creature: Do Y" you would get both effects as the first is triggering to the action of sacrificing, and is not stating a cost.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. What about sacrificing a creature to [Eldrazi Monument](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/5907/can-a-creatures-sacrifice-benefit-be-taken-when-it-is-sacrificed-to-eldrazi-mon)?

Comment: You would be able to claim a bonus for "whenever a creature is sacrificed" worded abilities, but cannot use it for sac x: do y because the Eldrazi is stating the sacrifice is an upkeep cost.