# Can a creature's sacrifice benefit be taken when it is sacrificed to Eldrazi Monument?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I asked a general question about [double sacrifice bonus](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/5892/can-you-claim-a-double-sacrifice-bonus/), but thought it better to ask a specific question. If a creature has a "Sacrifice this creature for X" ability, can you sacrifice it for that ability and satisfy the requirement of the [Eldrazi Monument](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEldrazi%20Monument%5d) with the same sacrifice (assuming it is done during the upkeep)?

**Oracle Text**:

- Creatures you control get +1/+1, have flying, and are indestructible.
- At the beginning of your upkeep, sacrifice a creature. If you can't, sacrifice Eldrazi Monument.

Comment: A lot of cards are worded to avoid this ambiguity. Instead of `If you can't...` they will say `If no creature was sacrificed in this way...`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

[Magic: The Gathering Comprehensive Rules](http://www.wizards.com/Magic/TCG/Article.aspx?x=magic/rules):

> 117.10. Each payment of a cost applies to only one spell, ability, or effect. For example, a player can't sacrifice just one creature to activate the activated abilities of two permanents that each require sacrificing a creature as a cost. Also, the resolution of a spell or ability doesn't pay another spell or ability's cost, even if part of its effect is doing the same thing the other cost asks for.

Answer (score 4):

No. Card text that instructs you to perform an action is telling you to perform that action **for this card**. Other similar actions you could take just because don't apply.

Consider the example of two [Propagandas](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=247417) on the field: paying (2) to satisfy one of them does not "pay off" the other.