# Sacrifice help With MTG

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have to sacrifice a creature every beginning of my upkeep and I play [Rescue from Underworld](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Rescue%20from%20Underworld), will I get past the sacrifice?

Thanks

Comment: The other question isn't exactly the same situation, but it should be close enough: you pay the extra cost for Rescue from the Underworld separately from whatever this other ability is, so you sacrifice twice.

Comment: Alternatively see http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/5892/can-you-claim-a-double-sacrifice-bonus

Comment: See my answer on that other question, it specifically addresses this question with my last paragraph about Mogg Fanatic.