# Magic The Gathering can this combo be done?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Quick question, can I use [Smallpox](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Smallpox) and choose to sacrifice [Strip Mine](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Strip%20Mine) but in response sacrifice Strip Mine to use it's effect too?

Comment: Also relevant: [Can I pay two different costs with the same payment?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/23986/6692) and [Can you claim a Double Sacrifice Bonus?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/5892/6692)

Comment: You can only respond to spells being cast and to abilities being added to the stack.  You can't respond to sacrifices